# How do I translate the content of a checkbox I created?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site, content translation works. Now I added a content type and used the checkboxes/dario buttons field for a new field. How can I translate the content of that field?

Let's say the checkboxes values are *male|Male* and *female|Female*. How can I use the Spanish translation for those values?

I found someone suggesting I had to use PHP fields, but I don't even see a PHP field there, although the module works in other places.

Comment: If you added your fields the right way, new strings for your labels should appear on the Translate Interface page, won't they ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart the *Content translation* module, the [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module is also required, to translate each field/entity.

[Content Translation (field translation) in Drupal 7: First steps](http://randyfay.com/node/88)  (also linked from the *Entity Translation* project page) is a good step-by-step guide on how to set this up.